# Android O monitoring network changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

What is now the recommended way to monitor connects and disconnects to and from WiFi networks?

Ordinarily, I would register a `BroadcastReceiver` in my manifest and listen for state changes.

Android O is going to make this impossible:

> Apps cannot use their manifests to register for most implicit broadcasts (that is, broadcasts that are not targeted specifically at the app).

What is the next best (least battery consuming) way to accomplish this same task?

My initial assessment is to create a `Service` that will monitor network state changes. I don't like the idea of running a permanent service for this purpose alone.

Comment: Isn't this restriction only if the app is in background. Though  it should work fine when the app is active and in foreground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: You can register the `BroadcastReceiver` in Java code, for instance, in an `Activity`'s `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`. This works only when your `Activity` is alive, of course.

Option 2: Use [`JobScheduler`](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129). You can schedule your jobs based on the available criteria in the `JobScheduler` like network connection availability.

> My initial assessment is to create a Service that will monitor network
>   state changes. I don't like the idea of running a permanent service
>   for this purpose alone.

Even this is not so simple. Your `Service` will be killed if the system finds it idle. If you don't want the `Service` to get killed, you have to start a `Foreground service`, but the catch is that a requires a notification to be shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library for this 
https://github.com/Ahmed-Abdelmeged/Networkito
Work with rxjava and Android Architecture Components and normal usage

Comment: I like the concept, especially using the new architecture components. However, what will happen if the App is in the background (for almost all the lifetime of the App)? The App will use conditions, such as are we on X wifi or connected to Y bluetooth device in order to know how to react to a certain event.

Comment: the lib only is registered dynamically not in the  manifest and only track the network info :] so when the app in the background nothing happen